# how can I defined this type data in golang

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have a data like `'{"{\"hello\":\"world\"}"}'`, it's a array json in postgresql.

I don't know how to handle it in golang.
I know I can define with `string` then use `json.Unmarshal` to slove, but I want to know if there is a way to get it in a `struct`

Comment: Your json does not represent an array. Arrays in json are denoted with `[ ]`. It's just a struct with another struct inside it.

Comment: the data looks an escaped json string with an object to me, not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you posted incorrect JSON and let's say it's `'{"hello": "world"}` 
A struct has a predefined fields, and with arbitrary JSON coming in it's impossible to know ahead. The possible solution would be to convert it into a map.

```
var data interface{}
b := []byte(`{"hello": "world"}`)
err := json.Unmarshal(b, &data)
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
fmt.Print(data)
```

As you print out the data, you'll probably get something like.
`map[hello:world]`

Which is in the form of `map[string]interface{}`.

Then you can use type switch to loop into the map structure until you **type assert** all the `interface{}`.

```
for k, v := range data.(map[string]interface{}) {
        switch val := v.(type) {
        case string:
                v = val
        default:
                fmt.Println(k, "is unknown type")
        }
}
```

Map is an ideal data structure when dealing with arbitrary incoming JSON. However, if the JSON is generated from an SQL table with predefined schemas, you can use a struct with the same structure instead of a map.

```
type Hello struct {
        Hello string `json:"hello"`
}
```